# React bootstrap checkbox not firing onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I have this loop on react that doesn't fire my `onChange`, when i click the checkbox:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons">

   {this.props.initialData.jobRequestStatusFilters.map(j =>

        <label key={j.jobRequestStatusID} className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">
            <input type="checkbox"  onChange={this.props.onChangeCheckBoxFilter.bind(this)} />{j.statusName}
        </label>

    )}

</div>
```

however when i remove the `className` of the label, its working fine
please help whats the problem.

Comment: Can you create a small working example showing your problem?